# iPython embed() automatically exits when calling script from bash file

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

I have a data processing pipeline setup that I want to debug. 
The pipeline consists of a bash script that calls a python script.

I usually use iPython's embed() function for debugging. However, when calling the python script from the bash file, the embed() function is called but immediately exited, without me being able to interfere. When running the same python program directly from the command line I don't observe this kind of behavior. Is this intended behavior or am I doing something wrong?

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)?
'follow up code prints here'
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code from the Bash script and the Python script. I was not able to reproduce this by making a bash script that runs a Python script that calls `embed()`.

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate the problem like this:

```
# test.py
import IPython
import sys
print(sys.stdin.read())
IPython.embed()
```

```
# session
❯ echo 'foo' | python test.py
foo

Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.10.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)?

❯ # I didn't quit on purpose, it happened automatically
```

STDIN is not a TTY, so I'm thinking that IPython is worried that the inbound text (via the pipe) won't be a user typing.  It doesn't want `foo` (from my example above) to spew into the IPython shell and do something unexpected.

You can work around this by getting your terminal id via the `tty` command, and redirecting stdin to the calling terminal after it has finished reading from the pipe, something like this:

```
with open('/dev/pts/16') as user_tty:
    sys.stdin=user_tty
    IPython.embed()
```

For more on ttys, see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93640).  Note also that if you put the wrong tty in there, input from some *other* terminal will control IPython.

I'm not sure if it's possible for IPython to know what the calling tty would have been, had it not been overwritten by bash to be the output-side of the pipe.

Edit: Here's my workaround put more simply: [How do I debug a script that uses stdin with ipython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979422/how-do-i-debug-a-script-that-uses-stdin-with-ipython)

Comment: IPython does not seem to be able to read the escape codes correctly when I do this. Things like the tab and arrow keys don't work.

Comment: You're right @HappyFace, I'm not sure why 2019-me didn't think that was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

I ran some experiments to see the behaviour. I noticed that IPython shows the console if any of the ancestor process is terminal.

Following are the files in /tmp directory:
**x.py**

```
import IPython 
IPython.embed()
```

**call.sh**

```
/usr/bin/python /tmp/x.py
```

**call2.sh**

```
/tmp/call.sh
```

**Experiment 1**
Running `python x.py` does open the IPython shell and waits.

**Experiment 2**
Running `bash call.sh` also opens the IPython shell and waits.

**Experiment 3**
Running `bash call2.sh` also opens the IPython shell and waits.

As you can see, it does not matter how deep is your IPython.embed call is. It always starts the interactive console and waits.

---

Lets try if it also works when we fork a new process.

**fork.sh**

```
/usr/bin/python /tmp/x.py &
```

**Experiment 4**
In this case, IPython shell started but immediately exited. Notice the & at the end. It starts a different process. IPython was not able to access the terminal in this case and hence exited gracefully.